# How to automatically play a music file as the user scrolls in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mobile, browser

## Background

- I am creating an event webpage with html, css and javascript.
- I want a music file to play when the user scrolls and reaches a certain position.

## Problem

- I've heard that randomly playing sounds is prevented for a good user experience, is this possible at all?
- Is it impossible for both desktop and mobile?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
  let soundPlayed = false;

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    // Check if the user has scrolled to a certain position
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    const threshold = 500; // Adjust this value based on your layout
    if (scrollPosition > threshold && !soundPlayed) {
      // Play the sound
      audio.play();
      soundPlayed = true;
    }
  });
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="your-sound-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

You're right to consider user experience when adding sound to a webpage. Auto-playing sound can be disruptive, especially if it happens unexpectedly or without user consent. However, triggering sound based on user action, like scrolling to a certain position, is feasible and can be done in a way that respects user preferences.

For desktop browsers, triggering sound based on scroll position using JavaScript is achievable. You'll want to detect the scroll event and check the scroll position against a certain threshold to decide when to play the sound.

However, for mobile devices, auto-playing sounds can be more challenging due to stricter policies aimed at preventing unexpected audio playback, especially when it comes to touch-based interactions. Many mobile browsers restrict auto-playing sounds to prevent intrusive experiences. On mobile, you might need to provide a clear user action (like a button press) to initiate the sound.